# Working with CSV and firebase

Tags: database, csv, firebase

I've been working on project where useres are able to load some data from the CSV, but each client have CSV with different structure. I can't ask them to change structure of the file because they are using those somewhere else. All of those files contains data that i need and I want to ask once at first upload which columns contains data i expect and then save this information so i don't have to ask them again.

Do you know how to ask client to somehow point those columns for me ? And how i should store those informations to use it next time ?

Comment: That sounds like an entire project, with many steps and technologies along the way. Stack Overflow is not well suited to these types of questions, because they're hard to provide a single, concise answer for. We'd essentially need to implement your entire use-case. Which specific step are you trying to take right now, that has you stuck?

Comment: I'm just starting this so i don't have any specific plan for this. I was writing this post to hear out some ideas ;) the thing is for example:
Id,Name,Price
1,a,10
2,b,20
3,c,30

Name,Price,Weight
a,10,22
b,20,33
c,30,50

And I want to collect only data Name and Price from those files. The problem is that names of those fileds can be diffrent, so I'm thinking about asking client to point/sort them or something like this. I believe that someone done something like this before and will tell some advices ;)